# C++ template class, how to declare a copy constructor for a specific situation?

Tags: c++, templates

Hi  (English is not my first language, please understand me even if I make mistakes! thank you!!)

I'm writing a template class that can contain a pointer.

```
template <typename T>
class SmartPtr {
private:
      T value;
public:
      SmartPtr() {};
      ~SmartPtr() {};

     SmartPtr(T* a)
     {
        this->value = *a;
     }
     SmartPtr(SmartPtr* a)
     {
          this->value = a->get_Value();
     }
     SmartPtr(SmartPtr const* a)
     {
          this->value = a->get_Value();
     }

     T get_Value()const{
          return this->value;
     }
};
```

This is template class called SmartPtr, and

```
class Test
{
public:
      Test() { std::cout << "Test::Test()" << std::endl; }

      Test(Test const&) { std::cout << "Test::Test(Test const&)" << std::endl; }

      ~Test() { std::cout << "Test::~Test()" << std::endl; }

      Test& operator=(Test const&)
      {
           std::cout << "Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)" << std::endl;
           return *this;
      }

      void print() const { std::cout << "Test::print() const" << std::endl; }
      void print() { std::cout << "Test::print()" << std::endl; }
};
```

this is my Test class.

When I declare

`SmartPtr<Test> ptr_t1 = SmartPtr<Test>(new Test);` in my main.cpp,

the result after compiling is

```
Test::Test()
Test::Test()
Test& Test::operator=(Test const&)
Test::~Test()
```

but the result that I want to get is

```
Test::Test()
Test::~Test()
```

Is there a specific template class copy contructor that I need to write in this situation?

Thank you so much for your patience!

Comment: See this question, not so sure if direct dupe though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list

Comment: `this->value = *a;` is assignment....

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you for the comment. Sorry, it's been 10 days with c++ and I do lack of knowledge. I should not make an assignment?

Comment: `SmartPtr<Test>` does not hold a pointer; it holds an **object** of type `Test`. A class that wraps a pointer would hold `T* ptr;`, not `T value;`.

Comment: @peteBecker Thank you for the comment! I'll start with that!

Comment: @HanseulSHIN - Well, you shouldn't make an assignment if you don't want the assignment operator (`=`) to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because of inside SmartPtr there is the `value` member variable:

```
template <typename T>
class SmartPtr {
private:
      T value; // here T is of class Test
... other stuff ...
}
```

When declaring

```
SmartPtr<Test> ptr_t1 = SmartPtr<Test>(new Test);
```

`ptr_t1` is construct, thus it's value is constructed.  So that's the first `Test()` constructor call.
The second constructor is the `new Test` (obviously).
Then, the `SmartPtr` is constructed, and inside, the `this->value = *a;` calls the `Test()` assignment operator.

Finally the `SmartPtr<Test>(new Test)` object is destructed, calling the destructor on the internal `value` object.

Note also because there was a `new Test` called, but no `delete`, there is a memory leak as well.

Comment: one last question please, so the the "value" member should be T* value instead of T value?

Comment: yes, and the destructor of SmartPtr should 'delete value'

Comment: Thank you for your time. have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

In order for only the constructor and destructor to be called, simply call the constructor directly:

> > SmartPtr ptr_t1(new Test);

Also, your SmartPtr class should store a pointer instead of the value. The value can reside in memory allocated by the call to new. Instead of:

> > private: T value;

write:

> > private: T* value;

This will ensure that the value isn't copied by the constructor, but is instead just pointed to. The value will still reside at the memory allocated by new.